# MySQL, SQL, PHP can I bring data from two tables joined by a third

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got an issue
I have 3 tables:

```
1 table named "members" (it has the members data, ID, Username, Password)
2 table named "schools" (it has list of schools ID, School_Name, School_Number)
3 table named "members_schools" (Here I two columns: User_ID, School_ID)
```

so I'm in a middle of a mess, I need to realize a sorting or grouping system
for example:
School Of St.Peter, Number 8, has an ID 1 in "schools" table

users have the right to choose ,from a list, this school and then I made a query to save their choice in "members_schools" something like:

```
User_ID  ::  Scool_ID
4        ::   1
```

This should bring back that: the user with ID:4 is attending the school with ID:1 which is here "School Of St.Peter"

now I tried to LEFT JOIN the tables among each others, but so far no luck!! I'm confused how to realize this thing, retrieving the data from the three tables and show them on a page in this order.

```
School               ::     No. Attenders
School Of St.Peter   ::     "NUMBER OF MEMBERS WHO HAVE APPLIED FOR THIS SCHOOL"
```

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use three tables until details of all users is required. To get a count we need to use only `schools` and `member_schools` table.

Use `LEFT JOIN` and then count the user_id in result

```
SELECT schools.School_Name AS School, IFNULL(COUNT(member_schools.User_ID),0) AS Number_of_Attenders
FROM schools LEFT JOIN member_schools
ON schools.ID = member_schools.School_ID
GROUP BY schools.School_name
```

**Sample Output**

```
School               ::     Number_of_Attenders
School Of St.Peter   ::     4
```

To show username of all members, use GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT schools.School_Name AS School, GROUP_CONCAT(members.Username) AS Attenders
FROM schools LEFT JOIN member_schools
ON schools.ID = member_schools.School_ID
INNER JOIN members
ON member_schools.User_ID = members.ID
GROUP BY schools.School_name
```

**Sample Output**

```
School               ::     Attenders
School Of St.Peter   ::     Isaac, Kevin, Rockse, Aish
```

Comment: I may need to get other details from the members table

Comment: Kindly tell me what exact result are you looking at ?

Comment: I just need to show the username of the member, something like connecting the two tables through the third one. thanks ))

Comment: Thank you alot for the help, I'll try this version and reply

Comment: I tried alot but not working! I need to apply the former code into a mySql query in PHP, that mixed it all up!!! plus, couldn't understand why the use of "AS" that made my head blow actually!! any easier way would be great.. thanks

Comment: Please post the php code too and let me know what exact results you want to display, it should be easy.

Comment: AS is used as an alias, check http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp. Basically to rename the long names

Comment: I have removed aliases, check now

Comment: Now that works in the phpMyAdmin, how could I echo the results in php??

Comment: Oh, Thanks alot, )) I found out how to express the query in php page, you were very handful )) I'm grateful for your help ))

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT schools.School_name AS `School`, COUNT(0) AS `Nr. Attenders`
FROM schools INNER JOIN members_schools ON schools.id = members_schools.School_ID
GROUP BY schools.School_name
```

Would give you the nr of members per school
The members table is not relevant for the number of attenders.

Comment: I'm not sure about this code, actually I am a beginner and the "s" and "m" are confusing me!! if you could write it in simpler way I'd appreciate it.!!

Comment: I have removed the aliases.

Comment: Thank you sir for the help, this answer is right too )) thanks alot